# Why does this Matplotlib heatmap have an extra blank column?

Tags: python, matplotlib

The question title speaks for itself. Take a look at the graphic produced by this code. Huh??

```
data = np.random.randn(20*15)
matrix = data.reshape((20,15))

xlabels = range(15)
ylabels = range(20)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(13,10))
heatmap = ax.pcolor( matrix, cmap=mpl.cm.PiYG, vmax=max(data), vmin=min(data))

plt.xticks(xlabels)
plt.yticks(ylabels)
plt.colorbar(heatmap)
```

[image]

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with int/float conversion errors in the internals. That is, `matplotlib` thinks the `x` limits are (0, 15.0...01) instead of (0, 15). If you set it explicitly (`ax.set_xlim(0, 15)`), or if you change `15` to `20` in your array sizes, there's no white column. Perhaps it is worth filing a bug on `matplotlib`.

Comment: @fjarri  Good call on the ax.set_xlim(0,15) works like a charm.

Comment: Works for me too. Nice catch! Post your comment as an answer and I'll report this as a bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(making an answer out of a comment)

I suspect it has something to do with `int` to `float` conversion errors in the internals of `matplotlib`. That is, `matplotlib` thinks the `x` limits are (0, 15.0...01) and rounds them to (0, 16) instead of keeping them at (0, 15). If you set it explicitly as

```
ax.set_xlim(0, 15)
```

or if you change `15` to `20` in your array sizes, there's no white column. Perhaps it is worth filing a bug on `matplotlib`.